# Anyone know what this physics lab equipment, found in the storage room, are? A resistivity kit or an optic bench? Any ideas? No identifying brand seen

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, electricity, experimental-physics, education

1.[image]

2.[image]

3.[image]

4.[image]

5.[image]

6.[image]

7.[image]

8.[image]

These equipment were found in the physics storage room. Unsure of how old they are or of their usage. They might be part of a resistivity kit or some sort of optic bench. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some of them are old  "Coefficient of thermal expansion" apparati...

Comment: Thank you so much DJohnM!!!! and thank you David White as well, I have now numbered the images and will make sure to do so for future questions as well!